# Send email to address getting from HTML input via Django

Tags: python, django, email

I'm searching for solution to this problem for many hours but can't find anything related. I want to get user's email from input and send mail from admin to that email address. Here are my codes:

`views.py`:

```
def index(request): 
    context = {
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
        'applicants':  Applicant.objects.filter(status=1),
        'empty_cards': range(4 - Applicant.objects.filter(status=1).count())
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('message_text'):
          Message.objects.create(
              sender_name = request.POST.get('sender_name'),
              sender_email = request.POST.get('sender_email'),
              message_text = request.POST.get('message_text'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject = 'Welcome !'
        message = 'We will back to you.'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = 'don't know how to get email'
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Which form fields contain the receiver email address(es)?

Comment: @schillingt ```<input type="email" name="sender_email"/>```

Comment: You want to send an email to the sender's email?

Comment: @schillingt, yes ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code I assume that you already have access to the user's mail
inside the request.

so you can try this:

```
sender_email = sender_request.POST.get('sender_email')
recipient_list = [sender_email]
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem - it's best to include explanation along with the solution.

Comment: In html the name of the element is how you can access the form data that the user posted. @vino just told you where and how to have access to a specific field. I suppose your next question is how to send an email from admin user?

Comment: @srvqaqa sorry, i didn't mean to come off that way. My intent was to isolate whats left of your problem (if any) and offer a solution once I confirmed your needs.